# Class and Call to a member function on a non-objec

Tags: php, class, oop

this time i have a hard problem. I have:

*[folder] (file)*

---

**Structure directory**

**[class]**
 *- (class.page.php)*
 *- (class.main.php)*
**[core]**
 - *(core.test.php)*

Now **class.data.php**

```
<?php
  class DataTools {

public function clean($string) {

    if (!empty($string)) {
        $string = addslashes($string);
        $string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
        $string = (string)$string;
        $string = stripslashes($string);
        $string = str_replace(" ", "", $string);
        $string = str_replace("(", "", $string);
        $string = str_replace("=", "", $string);
        return $string;
    } else {
        echo "Error";
        die();
    }
}
```

Now **class.page.php**

```
<?php
  class Page {
  public function __construct {
  include "class.data.php";
  $data = New DataTools();
  }
?>
```

Now **core.test.php**

```
<?php
  require_once "../class/class.page.php";
  $page = new Page;
  $nome = $data->clean("exemple"); // line 13
?>
```

When i open class.test.php it display this:
Fatal error: Call to a member function clean() on a non-object in /membri/khchapterzero/core/core.test.php on **line 13**( this is not important becouse i reduced the page for the topic, but the line in the original page was that i posted, the other line was comments)

Comment: mhh.. i don't understand... sorry!

Comment: i created it in class.page.php

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: data in /membri/khchapterzero/core/core.register_3.php on line 13

Comment: We're getting closer @RavenJe - if it isn't defined it is a non-object.

Comment: but what u mean with "defined"?? I defined the variable in class.page.php!!

Comment: PHP says *"Undefined variable: **data** ...."* PHP is telling you it is not defined.

Comment: yes but what mean defined?? when i need a variable i use this form: $variable = new ClassName; and stop <?php
  require_once "../include/class.data.php";
  $data = New DataTools();
?>

Comment: Apparently that did not work @RavenJe. Is it possible the path for the include is wrong?

Comment: the truth is that i include the page through a class. I update the code.

Comment: If class.data.php and class.page.php are in the same folder the `require_once()` in class.page.php is wrong.

Comment: Mh why? and what is the solution? ò.ò is include no require sorry.

Comment: Change the path, they are in the same folder.

Comment: Just to make sure, your code examples are missing some closing curly braces. I am assuming because you only copied here what is needed. you're also missing `()` on your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This seems ok, if all files are in one folder it works fine, i try and there was no error. check your structures and names.
I check on:

```
Test->
      class.data.php
      class.page.php
      core.test.php
```

in include only filename.
So checka again your paths

Comment: the things is that core.test.php is in another directory.

Comment: class.data.php and class.page.php are in class folder [class] class.test.php is in core folder [core]

Comment: core.test.php -> require_once "../class/class.page.php"
class.page.php -> require_once "class.data.php";

Answer (score 0):

$data is defined in the Page object, it is not available as a variable in the global scope. And because you are not storing it as a class member of the Page obejct, it is also lost when Page´s constructor resolves.

To fix this:

First make $data a class member of the Page class, so that it is not discarded after the constructor is done

```
<?php
  class Page {
  public function __construct {
  require_once "../include/class.data.php";
  $this->data = New DataTools();
  }
?>
```

Then, access this data variable *inside* the Page instead of trying to call $data directly:

```
$nome = $page->data->clean("exemple");
```

Comment: Now work but if i dont wont use this form? If i want use just $nome = $page->clean("exemple"); ?

Comment: You would fix the path in class.page.php and then say `$page = new DataTools;`

Comment: If you want to call ->clean on the Page but store the function in the DataTools, consider adding a ->clean() to the Page that just calls the ->clean() on its $data.